# Is Mobdro only for ARM now?

Tags: unknown-sources, arm-processors, x86-processors

I'm trying to use [Mobro](http://mobdro.com) on the Android SDK emulator.  It only seems to install on ARM images.  Is this a Mobdro limitation?

Answer (score 1):

There is a universal architecture (armeabi-v7a + x86)  available at [APKmirror repository (Mobdro Version: 2.1.4 (21412604))](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/mobdro/mobdro/mobdro-2-1-4-freemium-release/mobdro-2-1-4-freemium-android-apk-download/). This variant is larger in size (33.22 MB) than the arm counterpart.

For interest sake, I downloaded it and installed it, it is working fine on my `x86` virtual device (`API level 22`):

[image]

<sup>This was uploaded on May 10, 2018, I guess you could be right that it is now being developed only for arm architecture, if you desperately need to run it on x86 then grab it on this repo. This is just a speculation</sup>

Comment: Oops I apologise, even this universal version is giving odd error that it is an unsupported version or unsupported device when accessing streams. I guess I will have to take down the answer :(